# PHP, OOP: Why can't the array property of my class use properties & methods as values like an array outside of a class can?

Tags: php, arrays, class, methods, properties

So like the title says, I am having a hard time making an array property of one of my classes have it's values be declared as properties & methods.

I can successfully do this if the array is not a property of a class, but as soon as the array is dropped into a class, the script doesn't like those values, and throws me this error.

> **Fatal error**: Constant expression contains invalid operations in **C:\xampp\htdocs_webdev\repos\mcf\static\inc\classes\class.catalogue.php** on line **17**

I have both classes being included in a different `.php` called `inc.classes.php`. That file is then included in each page. Here is some code to better illustrate my issue,

**`Master Class File:`** `inc.classes.php`

```
// config
require_once('config/config.php'); // config file

// other tools
require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'inc/parsedown/Parsedown.php'); // tool that I am using for parsing .md files

// my classes
require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'inc/classes/class.vendor.php');
require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'inc/classes/class.catalogue.php');
```

**`Class A:`** `class.vendor.php`

```
class Vendor
{
  public $vendor = array(
    'foo' => array(
      'name' => 'Foo Inc.',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array(
      'name' => 'Bar Co.',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
  );

  public function get($data) {
    if (array_key_exists($data, $this->vendors)) {
      return $this->vendors[$data];
    } else {
      // throw error
    }
  }

  // Class methods...
}
```

**`Class B:`** `class.catalogue.php`

```
class Catalogue
{
  public $catalogue = array(
    '1' => array(
      $section = $markdown->text(file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR . catalogue/markdown/section1.md')),
      $link = 'catalogue/pdf/section1.pdf,
      $pdf = (ROOT_DIR . $link),
      'title' => 'Section One',
      'content' => mdReplace($section, $pdf, $link),
      'theme' => 'purple',
      'vendors' => array(
        1 => $vendor->get('foo'),
        2 => $vendor->get('bar'),
      ),
    ),
    // '2' ...
  );

  // Class methods...
}
```

> *(`mdReplace()` is a small function located in a seperate php file called `inc.functions.php`. It's purpose is to replace a few keywords inside of the `.md` files that contain the sections' content.)*

Apologies in advance if I am just blind as a bat right now and am missing something obvious.

Comment: if (array_key_exists($data, $this->vendors)) {       i believe you have a type here. corrected:  if (array_key_exists($data, $this->vendor)) {

Comment: @GoatHater It appears I do, thanks for noticing! Funny how typos are more noticeable to others.... damn tunnel vision.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read php oop [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) carefully, here what you will see:

> Class member variables are called "properties"... They are defined by using one of the keywords *public*, *protected*, or *private*, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

See the words

> must not depend on run-time information

And your current definition of `public $catalogue` is dependant of some data that will be evaluated later. That's why you have **fatal error**.

So, as said the solution is to fill `$catalogue` data by calling some function - either explicitly or in a `__construct` for example.

Comment: Thank you! Man, I knew I was glossing over something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You can't run methods on a class property like that. You'd need to set that up inside your construct:

```
class Catalogue
{
  public $catalogue = array();

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->catalogue = array(
    '1' => array(
      $section = $markdown->text(file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR . catalogue/markdown/section1.md')),
      $link = 'catalogue/pdf/section1.pdf,
      $pdf = (ROOT_DIR . $link),
      'title' => 'Section One',
      'content' => mdReplace($section, $pdf, $link),
      'theme' => 'purple',
      'vendors' => array(
        1 => $vendor->get('foo'),
        2 => $vendor->get('bar'),
      ),
    ),
    // '2' ...
  );
 }
  // Class methods...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As Farkie said, you can't run method calls on a class property like the way you did.

The reason is, those objects which you are trying to use are not initialised, and in order for them to work they must be initialised first.

Ex variables which can't directly be used in properly as they are not available to be used

> > - `$markdown`
> > - `$pdf`
> > - `$section`

So for Class B you need to have your code written inside the constructor.

However whatever you have done for Class A is perfectly acceptable and it should work. I could see that you have a typo in the variable name. It should be `$vendors` as you are trying to refer it inside the `function get()` as `$this->vendors[$data];`

The following will work

```
class Vendor
{
  public $vendors = array(
    'foo' => array(
      'name' => 'Foo Inc.',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array(
      'name' => 'Bar Co.',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
  );

  public function get($data) {
    if (array_key_exists($data, $this->vendors)) {
      return $this->vendors[$data];
    } else {
      // throw error
    }
  }

  // Class methods...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)
For both of my classes, I ended declaring the properties outside of `__construct()` and then assigning the type array and it's contents inside of `__construct()`. Just to be safe lol... Good to know that what I had for Class A at first was fine though.